# How to understand the explanation of conjugate point in Petersen's Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reading Petersen's Riemannian geometry.He uses distance function to establish three equations.

1.$L_{\partial_{r}} g=2 \operatorname{Hess} r$

2.$\left(\nabla_{\partial_{r}} \operatorname{Hess} r\right)(X, Y)+\operatorname{Hess}^{2} r(X, Y)=-R\left(X, \partial_{r}, \partial_{r}, Y\right)$

3.$\left(L_{\partial_{r}} \operatorname{Hess} r\right)(X, Y)-\operatorname{Hess}^{2} r(X, Y)=-R\left(X, \partial_{r}, \partial_{r}, Y\right)$

Then he says

> if we assume that the curvature is bounded,
> then equation (2) tells us that, if the Hessian blows up, then it must be decreasing
> as r increases, hence it can only go to $-\infty$:

I'm not sure what 'blow up'here means here, and I cannot understand why this implies that Hessian is decreasing.

He also says

> A conjugate point occurs when the Hessian of r
> becomes undefined as we solve the differential equation for it.

I cannot imagine when and why will the Hessian of r becomes undefined.

Other places in this section are difficult to understand too since there's only literal explanation without examples or calculations.

Any help will be thanked.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry and I have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix a unit tangent vector $v$ that is parallel along the geodeic. Let $H$ be the Hessian of $r$. Then equation 2 implies that
\begin{align*} \partial_r(H(v,v)) &= (\nabla_rH)(v,v)\\
& = -R(v,\partial_r,\partial_r,v) - H^2(v,v)\\
&=  -R(v,\partial_r,\partial_r,v) - g^{ij}H(v,\partial_i)H(v,\partial_j)
\end{align*}
Sayiing $H$ blows up along $R$ means that the last term approaches infinity. In particular, it becomes arbitrarily negative. That curvature is bounded implies that the first term is bounded. Therefore, as $r \rightarrow \infty$, the right side becomes negative. Therefore, $H(v,v)$ is decreasing for any parallel unit vector $v$.

As for an example where the Hessian blows up and therefore there is a conjugate point, I suggest looking at the sphere as described in 4.2.1 and see if you can figure out why, if $r$ is the distance from the north pole, then the Hessian of $r$ blows up at the south pole.

Comment: I tried this example, if I take metric on $S^{2}$ as $g=dt^{2}+\sin^{2}(t)d\theta^{2}$,then I take the distance on sphere to North Pole as distance function $r=t$，then the gradient of r is $∂r=∂t.$Then I calculate the hessian and get$Hessr=\sin(r)\cos(r)d\theta^{2}$(I may make mistake in this step).Then I get some trouble, I cannot see why this Hess blow up at $r=\pi$,where did I make mistake?

Comment: If I write the metric as $g=dt^{2}+\sin^{2}(t)d\theta^{2}=dt^{2}+g_{t}$ then $Hessr=\frac{\cos(r)}{\sin(r)}g_{t}$.I take a parallel unit vector field $v$ so $g_{t}(v,v)=1$ so $Hessr(v,v)=\frac{\cos(r)}{\sin(r)}$.This time it seems that $Hessr$ blow up.Is this right?